# If a migrated question is deleted, permanently redirect non 10k users to the question on the other site

Tags: feature-request, migration, 404-not-found

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Redirect links to moved questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32429/redirect-links-to-moved-questions)
>   [Why do migrated questions lack redirection via HTTP response status code 301 (Moved Permanently)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-do-migrated-questions-lack-redirection-via-http-response-status-code-301-mov)

So old links are not broken.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow
would permanently redirect to
[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm definitely up for this. Page Not Found error has hit me many, many times, when the real page is just moved away.