# Are links to Questions perpetually permalinks even after migration?

Tags: support, migration, permalink

At https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/142333

It states one side-effect of migration is:

- **The question is left as a stub**, or pathway to the new site, **for 30 days**, after which it is automatically deleted (again, this causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site).

Does deletion then cause the original link to the question to become dead links, or are they permalinks in perpetuity?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32434/142333 seems to imply it might.