# Reputation is based on opinions

Tags: discussion, reputation

Here's a contradiction I found:

- Questions on most Stack Exchange sites have to be seeking facts and not opinions
- Reputation in those same sites is based on people's votes, which are their opinions

If I'm wrong, then, on what bases do people decide wether to upvote or downvote a question?

Comment: Ironically enough, this very question is off topic, being opinion based.

Comment: Why do you think this is a contradiction? Yes, questions need to be fact-based, and yes, determining the quality of a question is an opinion, but these two things cover different aspects of the Q&A model of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does reputation really mean and do you pay attention to anyone's but your own?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12424/282094) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12427/282094 or https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/282094

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Voting, really, is *supposed* to be about how useful for the site a particular post is. That does imply a bit of bias, of course, but consider that the first thing you mentioned, the fact that questions on most SE sites need to not be opinion-based, is about whether or not a question is on-topic for the site, not necessarily whether the question is a *good* question. A question can simultaneously be on-topic *and* not a good question (i.e. it isn't necessarily useful to the site in the long term). Comparing the need for questions to be fact-based and the inherit opinionated nature of voting isn't really an apt comparison as the first concerns whether a question is fit for SE, and the other has to do with its quality and usefulness for the future.

When we determine the topicality of a question, and thus whether it should be closed, we typically don't insert opinions into the mix. Whether a question is a duplicate, needing details or clarity, or is opinion-based, is typically either a yes or no. Determining whether a question is useful for the site is *certainly* up to a degree of opinion, and likely always will be. You'll just have to live with that. This is doubly true [for Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), as voting is used as a way to signal agreement and disagreement with feature requests.

When posting on SE, you should be trying to ensure that your questions are:

1. On-topic
2. Well-researched
3. Well-written
4. Can apply to more than just yourself, if possible

If you tick all of those boxes, you've certainly earned an upvote from me, personally.

Answer (score 2):

Everything below is my opinion/experience, and what I often do. This shouldn't be treated as policy, but more how I think about voting

---

Tl;dr: people often decide based on their opinion of how good the question/answer is

> Questions on most Stack Exchange sites have to be seeking facts and not opinions

Yep, that's correct.

> Reputation in those same sites is based on people's votes, which are their opinions

Yes, but you are IMO missing something important. Votes (at least how I use them) is my opinion of how good the question/answer is. I don't think these two are mutually exclusive. Voting is always (somewhat) subjective, but it is (often) one's opinion how good a question (or answer) is.

I vote for a number of reasons, but the most common is on the tooltip (hover over the up/down vote buttons):

Upvote:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

Downvote:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Of course, people also vote for other reasons (for one, sometimes people downvote a totally off-topic question). Sometimes people vote for other reasons too, of course. Sometimes people vote up a question purely because they find it interesting*.

*I'm not saying to upvote bad questions, nor to judge these reasons, but they *are* some reasons for voting up/down